# Is it possible to check cases when exception is thrown with QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, exception, quickcheck

Suppose I have a function that should calculate some value in one case and
throw an exception otherwise. I would like to use QuickCheck to ensure my
function behaves correctly, however is not obvious how to perform this sort
of check. Is it possible and if yes, how to check that exception of certain
type is thrown and it contains correct information about its cause?

Comment: I guess you are talking about `Control.Exception` right? In this case the obvious thing would be to go with [`catch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:catch) and [`ioProperty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#t:ioProperty) (for quickCheck)

Comment: @Carsten, good, `catch` or `try` combined with `ioProperty` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed [`ioProperty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#v:ioProperty) is the key to this sort of test. You will need to use it in combination with [`catch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:catch) or [`try`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:try). Here I show the latter:

```
prop_exceptional :: Int -> Property
prop_exceptional n = ioProperty $ do
  result <- try . evaluate $ myDangerousFunction n
  return $ r === result
  where r | n == 0    = Left  MyException
          | otherwise = Right 42
```

Quite obviously, `myDangerousFunction` should throw `MyException` whenever it gets `0` and return `42` otherwise. Note the useful function [`evaluate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate), which you need to use to evaluate pure function in `IO` context to catch exceptions produced there.